# Can't Get 1:m VTiger Relationship to Show on "1" Side

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I am trying to implement a 1:m relationship between Contacts & Service Contracts in VTiger 6. We will use the relationship to track Users of our system. Each Contact should only be allowed to be link to 1 Service Contract at a time (1:m).

I was able to get the ServiceContract side of this working by using the following code:

```
require_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php';
$scmodule=Vtiger_Module::getInstance('ServiceContracts');
$scmodule->setRelatedList(Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Contacts'), 'Users',Array('SELECT'),'get_related_list');
```

This added a tab on the right side of Service Contracts titled "Users" with a SELECT button and allows us to ADD/REMOVE Contacts from the list.

However, what we would also like is to have a field on the Contacts page that shows which Service Contract they are linked to.

**UPDATE**:
I used the following code to add a single Service Contract field to Contacts:

`

```
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');
$module = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Contacts');
$blockInstance = Vtiger_Block::getInstance('LBL_CONTACT_INFORMATION', $module);
$fieldInstance = new Vtiger_Field();
$fieldInstance->name = 'SelectYourAccount';
$fieldInstance->label = 'Account';
$fieldInstance->uitype = 10;
$fieldInstance->typeofdata = 'V~O';
$blockInstance->addField($fieldInstance);
$fieldInstance->setRelatedModules(Array('ServiceContracts'));`
```

The above code worked fine and I have an Account field in contact details that I can link to a single Service Contract; however, when I select a Service Contract for a Contact and then go to the Users list on the Service Contract, the Contact isn't listed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**What i understand from your Question** is that Contact is your "1" module and Service Contract is "M(Multi Record)" module. Which means 1 Contact will have multiple Service Contract. So in vtiger Service Contract Related List is already given under Contact Module.Please check this image below.

[image: Service Contract Under Contact Module]

Next in Service Contract you will have Option to select Contact so that Contract will be liked with "1" Contact. See Screenshot here.

[image]

I Hope you will get clear picture after reading this of Relation in Vtiger.

Comment: HI Milan - Sorry for the confusion. I'm actually looking at the opposite. One Service Contract can have many Contacts (aka Users). However, each Contact can only be associated with a single Service Contract at a time (i.e. they can't login to our service under two different accounts)

Comment: Then you have added related list under service contract so you just have to add one relared field (uitype =10) for service contract module in contact module.  You have not mentioned about you did in contact module.

Comment: I had tried that using info here (https://discussions.vtiger.com/index.php?p=/discussion/171378/how-to-create-ui-type-10-field-for-any-module-/p1) but it didn't work. Is this the correct way to do that?

Comment: Yes its a correct way but if possible can you add your code here so can help you if any thing is wrong?

Comment: Code pasted in question, above.